# Enable other users to run Google App Script Function on protected sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I'm new to Google App Script and have created this function that allows members to submit data through a form. I want to protect the sheet where form records the data in so that the other users can't modify them post-submission. Problem is, when I lock the Data sheet, it prevents the other users from using the function with this error:

> Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.

I've seen similar questions answered but I'm having a hard time converting my script to the desired solution. I believe it involves using doGet but I haven't read up enough about this function. Can I ask for your help with this please?

Below is the function that I created

```
var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var codesBook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1L6ERNbbH1kbQtGnhgcsYKafkP57U8OSMNJQniF4R9_Y")
var formSheet = workBook.getSheetByName("Form")
var dataSheet = workBook.getSheetByName("Data")
var printOut = workBook.getSheetByName("Print Out")
var passwordsBook = SpreadsheetApp.openById('16CCT17bh4Gyu3zPV00a9T9cVPup0I_oLa94QkMEs_qc')
var passwordsSheet = passwordsBook.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

function submitForm(password, branch, index) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var data = formSheet.getRange("B3:C11").getValues();
  if ((data[4][1] + data[5][1] + data[6][1] + data[7][1] + data[8][1]) > 5) {
    ui.alert("Max 5 transactions are allowed only.")
    return
  }
  // data = [].concat(...data)
  if (data[0][0].toString().trim().length == 0 || data[1][0].toString().trim().length == 0 && data[2][0].toString().trim().length == 0 || data[3][0].toString().trim().length == 0 || (data[4][1] + data[5][1] + data[6][1] + data[7][1] + data[8][1]) < 1) {
    ui.alert("Please fill the form")
  }
  else {
    var output = []
    var errorMessage = [];
    for (var i = 4; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][1] == 0)
        continue;
      var codesSheet = codesBook.getSheetByName(data[i][0])
      var codes = codesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var countCodes = codes.filter((row) => row[2] != "VOID" && row[2] != true)
      if (countCodes.length - 1 < data[i][1]) {
        if ((countCodes.length - 1) == 0)
          errorMessage.push("No Codes are available for " + data[i][0] + " denomination")
        else
          errorMessage.push("Only " + (countCodes.length - 1) + " are remaining for " + data[i][0] + " denomination")
      }
      else {
        count = 0;
        for (var c = 1; c < codes.length; c++) {
          if (count == data[i][1])
            break;
          else if (codes[c][2] != "VOID" && codes[c][2] != true) {
            output.push([Utilities.getUuid(), data[0][0], data[1][0], data[2][0], data[3][0], data[i][0], codes[c][1], password, branch, "Hi " + data[0][0] + " please see your purchased wallet code of P" + data[i][0] + " below:" + codes[c][1]])
            codes[c][2] = true;
            count++;
          }
        }
        codesSheet.getRange(1, 1, codes.length, codes[0].length).setValues(codes)
      }
    }

    if (errorMessage.length > 0)
      ui.alert(errorMessage.join("\n"))
    else {
      if (output.length > 0) {
        dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output)
        var printOutData = output.map((r) => [r[0], r[5], r[6]])
        printOutData.push(['Date of Purchase', new Date(), ''])
        printOut.getRange("A7:C").clearFormat().clearContent()
        printOut.getRange("A1").setValue("Hi, " + output[0][1])
        printOut.getRange(7, 1, printOutData.length, printOutData[0].length).setValues(printOutData).setNumberFormat("@").setFontColor("blue").setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setHorizontalAlignment("center")
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var lr = printOut.getLastRow();

        printOut.getRange(lr, 1).setFontColor("black").setFontWeight("bold")
        printOut.getRange("B" + lr + ":C" + lr).merge()

        var note = [['Note: Should you have any issues in using the voucher codes, please raise the issue'], ['24 hours of purchase. Please present this printout to the Grab representative to '], ['validate your purchase']]

        var instructions = [['Instructions:'], ['1. Pumunta sa iyong Cash Wallet sa Grab Driver app at i-click ang Top-up.'], ['2. Ilagay ang amount na gusto mong i-top up at pindutin ang Next.'], ['3. Pindutin ang Top Up Now para makumpleto ang transaction.']]
        printOut.getRange(lr + 2, 1, note.length, 1).setValues(note).setFontColor("red").setFontWeight("bold")
        printOut.getRange(lr + 6, 1, instructions.length, 1).setValues(instructions).setFontColor("black").setFontWeight("bold")
      }
      // passwordsSheet.getRange("C" + index).setValue(true)
      formSheet.getRange("B3:C6").clearContent()
      formSheet.getRange("C7:C11").clearContent()
      ui.alert("All codes assigned successfully.")
    }
  }

}



function authenticate() {
  var passwords = passwordsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(passwords)
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please enter the password to continue...");

  //Get the button that the user pressed.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();

  if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
    Logger.log("The user clicked the [OK] button.");
    var pwd = result.getResponseText();
    if (pwd.trim() == "") {
      ui.alert("Password must not be empty.")
      return
    }
    var matched = false
    for (var i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
      if (passwords[i][0].toString().trim() == pwd.trim()) {
        // passwordsSheet.getRange("C" + (i + 1)).setValue(true)
        matched = true;
        submitForm(passwords[i][0], passwords[i][1], i + 1)
      }
    }
    if (!matched) {
      ui.alert("Incorrect Password!")
    }
  } else if (button === ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    Logger.log("The user clicked the [X] button and closed the prompt dialog.");
  }

}
```

Comment: How is `submitForm` supposed to be triggered? Also, you don't want users executing this function to have access to the spreadsheet, but at the same time you are adding UI sections (e.g. `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();`) that those same users are supposed to view? I don't think this workflow makes sense. I think deploying your script as a webapp, as suggested in the existing answer, could be a way forward, but your current workflow doesn't seem appropriate for this. What form are you talking about, and how users are supposed to submit it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) the `doGet(e)` with your acces rights. The users call's this function via the deployment url instead of calling the function directly. I only can not see how you passing the password, branch and index in the function?

Basic setup:

```
function theFunctionThatWillBeCalledByTheUser(){
  const doGetDeploymentUrl = 'xxx'
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(doGetDeploymentUrl)
}

function doGet(e){
  //Calling the function:
  submitForm()

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ message: 'ok' })).setMimeType(
    ContentService.MimeType.JSON
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33, I tried using the above set up but when I run the function, it does nothing and it says that the script has finished running

Comment: btw I've modified the script to show the whole function